# htaccess redirection is not working putting in name "-"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

htaccess redirection is working perfectly in my localhost wampserver. But when uploaded to server(to my site) names with rewrite rule contains "-" is not working.

For example - below code is working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^supportus/{0,1}$  supportus.php [QSA,L]    
</IfModule>
```

But this isn't working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^arts-exhibitions/{0,1}$  arts.php [QSA,L]    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the - `arts\-exhibitions`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" and what error are you getting?

Comment: with \ is not working either:

The value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.
arts-exhibitions:25 The value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
arts-exhibitions:25 The value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
arts-exhibitions:25 The value "0;" for key "user-scalable" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
arts-exhibitions:25 Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.

Comment: May be it is not truly dash symbol (0xad)? Dash should be working fine without escaping. Try copy-paste working .htaccess from http://pastebin.com/DzuxKfz4

Comment: not working I tryed !

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it needed "/" and only $. The below code is working perfectly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^art-exhibitions$  /arts.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```